# How do I stop FCKeditor reverting html entities back to their unicode characters

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

I am having a problem with FCKeditor reverting html entities entered in the source view back to their original unicode representations. 
For example when I enter `&euro;` into the source view, switch to html and then back to source view, the entity is replaced by an actual € symbol. 
The bigger problem, as a result, is that this unicode character is then sent back to the server on submit causing character encoding issues with the underlying database table.
Anyone else come across this?
I have tried many combinations of config settings but all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a configuration setting - `FCKConfig.ProcessHTMLEntities=true`.

Altough I had tried changing this in fckconfig.js, I did not realise that the value was being over-ridden in a secondary custom configuration file which had been created by a previous developer.

Thanks Anne.

Answer (score 3):

What version of FCKeditor are you using?  The current version is 2.6.3.  I tested the € symbol in their demo by copying `&euro;` into source view, switched back to display and then back to HTML the ASCII `&euro;` was retained correctly.  As such it sounds like there might be a configuration problem with your install of FCKEditor or you need to upgrade.

**Edit:** Just found this gem in the FCKEditor documentation: http://docs.fckeditor.net/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Configuration_Options/ProcessNumericEntities

Comment: That's what I see in my installation as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you need same setting for CKEditor 3, you can use this:

```
config.entities = false;
```

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.entities